# how to find Distinct data from database when foreign key is duplicated

Tags: sql-server

```
Candidate_ID IsProccesd?
        22             1
        22             0
```

**OUTPUT** :None

```
Candidate_ID IsProccesd?
        22             0
        22             0
```

**OUTPUT**: Record Deleted

i want to Query for this data

Comment: Not a detailed question at all. Can you post sample data, expected output and what you have tried so far?

Comment: My Candidate_ID is 22 for both Row but IsProcessed is 1 and 0 When it is zero and zero delete record or else keep it as it is

Comment: That doesn't help explain this at all. Keep in mind we have no idea what you are trying to do here. You need to explain it clearly. That means providing details. Vague explanations do not help us understand your requirements. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH ToDelete AS (
   SELECT Candidate_ID, IsProcessed,
          COUNT(CASE WHEN IsProcessed = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
          OVER (PARTITION BY Candidate_ID) AS cnt
   FROM mytable 
)
DELETE FROM ToDelete
WHERE cnt = 2
```

The above query will remove `Candidate_ID` partitions having two records with `IsProcessed = 0`. This will work as long as each `Candidate_ID` partition has at most two records. You may need to adjust the query otherwise.

Comment: Thank U for ur hrlp @Giorgos Betsos

Comment: @Akki Glad I was able to help. Please mark this or any other answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.